# node server to render django template

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, django

We are trying to develop a multi-page web site using Django template. We have make some effort to separate font-end from Django project using webpack. [webpack-jade-multipage-starter](https://github.com/njleonzhang/webpack-jade-multipage-starter)

we using Jade as html pre-complier, Babel as js pre-complier and SCSS as css pre-complier. The output looks like this:

[image]

**static** folder contains **css**, **js** and **img**.

**template** is the django template

**html in the dist** folder is static page.

Now the problem is that, everytime when we want to test django template, we need to build out project and copy django template to django project's template folder(although we have gulp to do this), and refresh the page in browser. is there a node-django server, which can render django template in node, so that we can make a live reload in this scenario.

**update: try to configure swig as the template render engine:**

```
var app = express()

var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig)

var devMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    chunks: false
  }
})

var hotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler)
// force page reload when html-webpack-plugin template changes
compiler.plugin('compilation', function (compilation) {
  compilation.plugin('html-webpack-plugin-after-emit', function (data, cb) {
    hotMiddleware.publish({ action: 'reload' })
    cb()
  })
})

// serve webpack bundle output
app.use(devMiddleware)

// enable hot-reload and state-preserving
// compilation error display
app.use(hotMiddleware)

// serve pure static assets
var staticPath = path.posix.join(config.dev.assetsPublicPath, config.dev.assetsSubDirectory)

app.use(staticPath, express.static('./static'))

app.set('views', webpackConfig.output.publicPath)
app.engine('html', swig.renderFile)
app.set('view engine', 'html')

app.set('view cache', true);
swig.setDefaults({ cache: false });

router.get('/index', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('post_index.dj.html', {});
});

app.use(router);
```

in the router, it seems template engine is trying to find template in the disk, not in the memory. I don't know how to config it.

Comment: This is not a common setup. Maybe you can try swig, which uses the django template syntax in node. http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/

Comment: @Wtower I will have a try. not sure, if the syntax is 100% match

Comment: It should be, although these things not always work as expected. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Wtower I am pending at the node configuration now. I use webpack-dev-middleware for live reload, but what it hosts is in memory, so It seems it is not easy to configure a template engine for it.